# Spyder python editor: turn off whole-line tab when tabbing mid-line

Tags: python, editor, indentation, spyder

Imagine I am standing (i.e., the cursor is located) somewhere mid-line in a given line of my Spyder editor.

Working always only with interesting integers, I could be at this line, say:

```
an_interesting_integer = 4
```

the cursor is right before "=" and thus right after "an_interesting_integer ", say.

Then I press "tab".

What I want is just the equal sign to be tabbed, but what happens in my Spyder editor is that the whole line is tabbed.

So instead of:

```
an_interesting_integer     = 4
```

I get:

```
    an_interesting_integer = 4
```

How can I turn off this "whole-line-tabbing" thing.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spyder v. 4.0 or higher:

> Tools >>> Preferences >>> Editor >>> Source code >>> Uncheck "Tab always indent".

Other versions:

> Tools >>> Preferences >>> Editor >>> Advanced settings >>> Uncheck "Tab always indent".

Comment: For more recent versions of Spyder (I'm on 4.1.5), this option is under Tools >> Preferences >> Editor >> Source Code